# Stripe example java server in spring boot ? Incompatible types: Optional<StripeObject> cannot be converted to Source

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, stripe-payments

In the java server for stripe payment demo, there are 4 java type cast such as this one:

- https://github.com/stripe/stripe-payments-demo/blob/add-react-client/server/java/src/main/java/app/fulfillment/Fulfillment.java#L62

I was not able to run that server due to the lack of documentation. I am using IDEA Intellij 2020 and I have a spring boot 1.5.9 server where I am willing to implement it.

After copying the code in intellij, and adapting the controller for spring, I have many cast errors:

```
error: incompatible types: Optional<StripeObject> cannot be converted to Source
```

Why can the original perform that cast and why can't my spring implementation perform it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the example you are referring to is using deprecated API, and actual version of `EventDataObjectDeserializer` [returns `Optional<StripObject>`](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/stripe/model/EventDataObjectDeserializer.java#L67-L86) so you should update your code as recommended:

```
Event event = Webhook.constructEvent(payload, sigHeader, secret);
EventDataObjectDeserializer dataObjectDeserializer = event.getDataObjectDeserializer();
if (dataObjectDeserializer.getObject().isPresent()) {
    StripeObject stripeObject = dataObjectDeserializer.getObject().get();
    doSomething(stripeObject);
} else {
    throw new IllegalStateException(
    String.format("Unable to deserialize event data object for %s", event));
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so you are suggesting to call isPresent first and add .get to the failing line and that's it?